# While loading the trained transformer model in variable, getting error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'full'

Tags: spacy-transformers

```
ner = spacy.load(model_path)
```

I am running the above command and model_path has path to trained model. I am getting error

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'full'.

I have downloaded the en_core_web_trf model.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.